# Is it possible to display applets on dwm status bar?

Tags: window-manager, dwm, tiling-wm

Does `dwm` support **displaying of applets on its status bar ?**

Applets like the `nm-applet, pamac-tray` or `cbatticon` ?

On `i3` you just run them and their icons just show up on the `i3bar`, but this is not the case with `dwm`.

**Is this possible with somekind of available patch ?**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a system tray.
Check out [suckless's tray](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray/).